# Enviar value selecionado do option por parâmetro

Tags: java, html, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação *Java* em que pego os dados do banco de dados e apresento em um `<select><option>` mas não sei como pegar o `value` selecionado e enviar por parâmetro.

> JSP

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${!empty param.descricao}">
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.produtos}" var="registro"> 
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6"> 
  <h3>${registro.descricao}</h3>
  <p>${registro.codigo}</p>
  <div class="linha_compra"></div><br/><br/> 
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
  <p>${registro.valor}</p> 

  <select id="parcelas">
   <option value="1"> ${registro.prod_parc1}</option>
   <option value="2">${registro.prod_parc2}</option>
   <option value="3">${registro.prod_parc3}</option>
   <option value="4">${registro.prod_parc4}</option>
   <option value="5">${registro.prod_parc5}</option>
   <option value="6">${registro.prod_parc6}</option>
   <option value="7">${registro.prod_parc7}</option>
   <option value="8">${registro.prod_parc8}</option>
   <option value="9">${registro.prod_parc9}</option>
   <option value="10">${registro.prod_parc10}</option>
  </select><br/><br/>  
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
   <button type="button" onclick="" class="botao_comprar"><a href="http://localhost:8080/EccomerceJSP2/Carrinho?descricao=${registro.descricao}&valor=${registro.valor}&parcela=">COMPRAR</a></button> 
  </div>
 </div>
</c:foreach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia amigo, antes de te ajudar, vamos considerar algumas mudanças.

Você está usando um *link* para fazer uma requisição, no caso:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/EccomerceJSP2/Carrinho?descricao=${registro.descricao}&valor=${registro.valor}&parcela=">COMPRAR</a>
```

Quando se utiliza uma âncora com `href` você automaticamente envia a requisição com método **GET**.

De acordo com os padrões *HTTP*, o método **GET** deve ser usado para recuperar os dados e não para enviar ou editar nada, apenas recuperar. O que seu código está fazendo é enviando dados na *URL* para alguma lógica de negócio no *backend*.

Isso além de não seguir padrões, não é seguro. Beleza, sua requisição não tem nenhum dado sensível, mas imagine que você queira adicionar o campo de cartão de crédito, por exemplo. Você vai enviar o número do cartão de crédito do usuário na *URL*? Óbvio que não.

Geralmente, se utiliza o parceiro seguro do **GET**, o método **POST**.

Este método não cacheia nem mantem no histórico do browser os dados do usuário, além de os enviar de maneira segura para o *backend*. Não aparece na *URL*, e é bem mais difícil de interceptar do que o simples método **GET**.

Para se utilizar, você abre uma *tag* `form` e inicia o atributo *method* para "POST".

Ficaria algo como:

```
<form method="POST"></form>
```

A *tag* `form` tem outro atributo importante, que é o *action*.

Este atributo especifica a URL na qual você vai enviar a requisição POST.

Ficaria algo como:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/EccomerceJSP2/Carrinho"></form>
```

Note que foi retirado do *link* os atributos na *URL*, você agora irá envia-los via **POST**.

Basta criar o formulário da seguinte forma:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/EccomerceJSP2/Carrinho">
 <input name="descricao" value="${registro.descricao}" readonly="readonly"/>
 <input name="codigo" value="${registro.codigo}" readonly="readonly"/>
 <input name="valor" value="${registro.valor}" readonly="readonly"/>
 <select id="parcelas" name="parcelas">
  <option value="1"> ${registro.prod_parc1}</option>
  <option value="2">${registro.prod_parc2}</option>
  <option value="3">${registro.prod_parc3}</option>
  <option value="4">${registro.prod_parc4}</option>
  <option value="5">${registro.prod_parc5}</option>
  <option value="6">${registro.prod_parc6}</option>
  <option value="7">${registro.prod_parc7}</option>
  <option value="8">${registro.prod_parc8}</option>
  <option value="9">${registro.prod_parc9}</option>
  <option value="10">${registro.prod_parc10}</option>
 </select>
 <button type="submit" class="botao_comprar">COMPRAR</button>
</form>
```

Note que cada *input* tem um atributo `name` que é justamente os parâmetros que você estava passando na *URL* anteriormente.

Na sua *Servlet*, agora, ao invés de implementar o método `doGet`, você vai implementar o método `doPost` e vai recuperar os dados da mesma forma:

```
request.getParameter("descricao"); //descrição vindo do formulário
```

Espero ter te ajudado. Qualquer dúvida é só comentar.

Abraços.

Comment: obrigado por responder Andrew Ribeiro. mas agora como vou pegar o option selecionado e enviar o value para servlet ?

Comment: e no caso não estou usando o form pois estou mostrando os dados utilizando um forEach

Comment: Não precisa. A estrutura que eu expliquei ali ja faz isso por você. 
Quando um usuário seleciona e envia, la na *Servlet* você já terá acesso ao `value` da **option** através de `request.getParameter("parcelas");`.

Comment: Exemplo, quando o usuário selecionar a parcela 5, você não precisará montar a *URL* com o `value` do **option** que contém a parcela 5. Basta dar um **submit** no form que a parcela 5 ja vai estar associada ao parametro "parcelas" automaticamente.

Comment: Outra duvida Andrew estou mostrando os dados  de acordo com um <c:choose><c:when  test="${!empty param.descricao}"> e um 
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.produtos}" var="registro"> então as tag lib devia ir antes ou depois da tag <form>?

Comment: E não quero apresentar os dados da descricao do produto, codigo e valor no input e sim apresenta-los como titulos

Comment: @User1999, pra cada laço do **forEach**, você vai montar um **form**.
Então as *tags libs* se abrem antes do **form** e se fecham depois do **form**.

Comment: não quero apresentar o dado da descrição do produto no input e sim apresenta-los como titulos então se eu colocar assim  <h3 name="descricao" value="${registro.descricao}"></h3> iria mandar o value do <h3> para servlet ?

Comment: @user1999 Não, só inputs são enviados no post. Você pode é deixar o <h3 value="${registro.descricao}" /> e usar um <input type="hidden" name="descricao" value="${registro.descricao}" /> para enviar o dado.

Comment: @Andrew Ribeiro POST absolutamente não criptografa os dados.

Comment: @mari, perfeito.
Me equivoquei com relação a criptografia, estava com https na cabeça.
Resposta ja foi editada.